# Rails cache: what is it and how it should be used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have an app I am building that has a user fill out a form and stores the information in various files until the end where it uploads the data, one file at a time, to a single source.

I was wondering if this is the same idea as caching, or if I should be using some sort of built in rails cache to do this instead.

And if so, what is the difference between a cache and what I am doing (storing data temporarily in files I create)?

Are there any really good articles I could read that would help me understand caching and the various benefits of caching? That is.. if it is more than what I assume a cache to be (just reserved temporary memory)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your user form consists of different stages? Instead of writing to files which is a slow process, you should consider saving them in temporary variables or cookies in browser(which will have added benefit of allowing resuming of form from where user left off).

By Rails cache, you mean server side caching. i.e. you store something which is repetitive and not likely to change. Examples include static contact us pages, headers of pages etc. Wherever you feel that something is done multiple times without any changes in the end result, you can cache it away.

As you can see, it is not exactly relevant to your scenario. Consider the session storage if the form is not abnormally long.

Note: Do a fair bit of reading on cache expiry and strategies before you get into that. Caches if done lightly can raise some very-hard-to-track bugs.